# Android sdk Update contact with contact provider

Tags: android, android-contacts

I first do a request like that :

```
Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;

    String[] projection = new String[]{
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
    };

    Cursor cursor = resolver.query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

    ArrayList<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<> ();

    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst ()) {
        do {
            Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact.Id = cursor.getLong (cursor.getColumnIndex (projection [0]));
            contact.DisplayName = cursor.getString (cursor.getColumnIndex (projection [1]));
            contact.PhotoId = cursor.getString (cursor.getColumnIndex (projection [2]));
            contact.PhoneNumber = cursor.getString (cursor.getColumnIndex (projection [4]));

            contactList.add (contact);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());

        cursor.close();
    }

    return contactList;
```

Then I use the ID returned by this first request to update a contact like so :

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<>();

    // Name
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
            .newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withSelection(
                    ContactsContract.Contacts._ID
                            + "=? AND "
                            + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE
                            + "=?",
                    new String[] {
                            String.valueOf(contact.Id),
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE })
            .withValue(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, contact.DisplayName)
            .build());

    try {
        resolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But unfortunately the update part is not working. 
Any idea of how to use result from the first request with the update request ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't update a field from the `Contacts` table by updating the `Data` table.
All the fields in your projection that come from `Contacts.X` are added via an implicit join, but actually belong to a different table.

If I understand correctly, you're trying to update a contact's display-name, here's how to do it (make sure you import all classes from `ContactsContract`):

```
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
        .newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI)
        .withSelection(Data.CONTACT_ID + "=? AND " + Data.MIMETYPE + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.Id), StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE })
        .withValue(StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, contact.DisplayName)
        .build());
```

Also, FYI, you don't need to use `cursor.getColumnIndex` in your first query, just do:

```
contact.Id = cursor.getLong(0);
contact.DisplayName = cursor.getString(1);
contact.PhotoId = cursor.getString(2);
contact.PhoneNumber = cursor.getString(4);
```

**Docs**

> Some columns from the associated raw contact are also available
>   through an implicit join. The other columns are excluded as
>   uninteresting in this context.

...

> The ID column for the associated aggregated contact table
>   ContactsContract.Contacts is available via the implicit join to the
>   ContactsContract.RawContacts table, see above. The remaining columns
>   from this table are also available, through an implicit join. This
>   facilitates lookup by the value of a single data element, such as the
>   email address.

Comment: great, thank you! I'll try as soon as I have time and tell you if it works. So I just had to specified Contacts.CONTENT_URI as the URI instead of Data.CONTENT_URI ?I did that because I thought display_name is stored in data. It mean the update query will find the corresponding data table by itself ?

Comment: `DISPLAY_NAME` is not stored in `Data`, only in `Contacts`, so you have to modify `Contacts` table only. When you **query** from the `Data` table (like in your first query) the provider will know to fetch the `DISPLAY_NAME` from the `Contacts` table

Comment: Ok I see, thank you. Where I can find this information about DISPLAY_NAME ? I read the doc and it say "Display name, phone number, email, postal address, photo, and website detail rows are all found in the ContactsContract.Data table." (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html) that's why it confused me.

Comment: see my edit. basically you're right, the display-name is actually saved in its own mimetype (CommonDataKinds.StructuredName) in the `Data` table, but you don't need to worry about that, because it's also stored in the `Contacts` table where it is available for querying such as yours

Comment: ok so I tried but it didn't works. It do nothing. No error and no update. Any idea ?

Comment: seems like i was wrong, you do need to edit directly in the Data table, I've updated the code, hope this works now

Comment: no sorry, I tried and it still do nothing. No exception, no update

Comment: `applyBatch` returns an array of `ContentProviderResult` you should store the result to a variable, and check its values (uri and count)